# Check the identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin^{2p}\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)= 2^{-2p-1}{2p \choose p}(2n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

We want to evaluate the sums
$$S_{n,p}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^{2p}\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)$$
So we try many attempts by experimenting with the sum calculator which leads us to the result 
$$S_{n,p}={{2p \choose p}(2n+1)\over 2^{2p+1}}$$
**How do we proof that the above result is correct or not?**

Comment: Is $p$ taken to be a natural number?

Comment: Test with $n:=1$ : Is this correct ?!?

Comment: $n=1$ and $p=3$ does not work

Comment: @GuachoPerez : That's what I meant but I hoped the OP will test it himself. :)

Comment: It seems like it might work for $n > 1$, though.

Comment: Mathematica shows it works only for $p=2$ and $n=1$, i checked it for $p<10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $p$ is a positive integer and letting $\omega = e^{\pi i/(2n+1)}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sin^{2p}\left( \frac{k\pi}{2n+1} \right) 
&= \frac{1}{2^{2p}} \sum_{j=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{j} (-1)^{p-j} \omega^{2k(p-j)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{2p+1}} \sum_{j=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{j} (-1)^{p-j} \left( \omega^{2k(p-j)} + \omega^{-2k(p-j)} \right).
\end{align*}

Now utilizing the [Dirichlet kernel formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel), we obtain

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \omega^{2k(p-j)} + \omega^{-2k(p-j)} \right)
= -1 + \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \omega^{2k(p-j)}
= \begin{cases}
2n, & 2n+1 \mid p-j \\
-1, & 2n+1 \nmid p-j
\end{cases}.$$

So it follows that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^{2p}\left( \frac{k\pi}{2n+1} \right) 
&= \frac{1}{2^{2p+1}} \sum_{j=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{j} (-1)^{p-j} \left( (2n+1)\mathbf{1}_{\{ 2n+1 \mid p-j \}} - 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{2n+1}{2^{2p+1}} \sum_{l} (-1)^{l} \binom{2p}{p+(2n+1)l},
\end{align*}

where the sum in the last line runs over all integers $l$ such that $|l| \leq \frac{p}{2n+1}$. In particular, if $p \leq 2n$ then only $l = 0$ contributes to the sum and we retrieve OP's formula.

Comment: Also check my previous computation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932029/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-k-0n-1-sint-pi-k-2n/1935309#1935309