# Can we compute the derivative of trig functions with Riemann sums and FTOC? (And any other special cases like this?)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, riemann-sum

Thanks to an answer from [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1931543/272831), we can compute the following integral through Riemann sums:

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b\cos(x)\ dx & =\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}\right) \\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(b-a)}{n}\,\cos\left(\frac{(b-a)+(a+b) n}{2 n}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{b-a}{2 n}\right)} \\
& =\sin(b)-\sin(a) \\
\end{align}$$

And so we have

> $$\int_a^b\cos(x)\ dx=\sin(b)-\sin(a)$$

without the use of the FTOC.

Now, if we include the knowledge of the FTOC, does this imply that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$$

And thus we have effectively calculated the derivative of a trig function without that silly $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}h$?  Or is the implication not so direct?  If so, how would we make the connection?

---

And just out of interest, are there any derivatives that can be calculated through Riemann sums and reversed FTOC?

Comment: That is an incredibly complicated way to show $\sin' x = \cos x$.  It depends on identities that are more involved than the simple trigonometric addition formula and estimate for $\sin x$.  Why do you call the usual way of finding $\sin' x$, which depends on $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} (\sin h)/h$,  silly?

Comment: My guess is that the fact that the telescoping sum converges to $\sin(b)-\sin(a)$ is equivalent to $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} =1$.

Comment: @KCd Just that the limit is not algaebraically doable in any easy sense.  I felt this method was more algebraic.  But sure, it is incredibly complicated.

Comment: But like the usual method of finding $\sin' x$, this method you write about depends on the addition formula for a trig function and that is definitely *not* algebraic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like user Matthew Leingang commented, it is not possible to ignore the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1\tag{1}$$ when you are dealing with any analytic (non-algebraic) properties of $\sin x$. The limit of Riemann sum in your question evaluates to $\sin b - \sin a$ precisely because of the limit $(1)$ (check the factor $$\frac{b - a}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sin\dfrac{b - a}{2n}}$$ in your Riemann sum).

It should be obvious that the limit formula $(1)$ can't be derived using any sort of algebraic tricks precisely because function $\sin x$ is transcendental. An analogy is that the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ involves only basic algebra (and a little bit of number theory), but the proof of irrationality of $\pi$ is simply not possible through algebra.

Regarding computing derivatives via the complicated route of "evaluating limit of Riemann sum and then using FTC" I should say the process is similar is establishing the formula $$n^{2} - (n - 1)^{2} = 2n - 1\tag{2}$$ from the complicated formula $$1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n - 1) = n^{2}\tag{3}$$ The simpler and preferable route is to prove $(3)$ using $(2)$ and not the other way round.